# RDLC Report Jump to Another Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

(Windows application)

I am very new to RDLC Report and I  have drill Down Report In my Project. I read Many Forums and tutorial but i did not find any solution.

I Have Added `Report1.Rdlc` In my project. There is One TextBoxName on that. What I want To Do is on `TextBoxName` Click I want To jump On `Report2.Rdlc` But When I Set The properties Of `TextboxName` Report2 Is not Showing in DropDown

When I Watch the videos in that Dropdown Automatically Appears if there is any rdlc report in Project but in my case it does not

I take `Crystalreportviewer` for `Report1` and in `CrystalreportViewer` task i choose Report1 So Report2 will Open in Same Viewer..?????

i tried to give path in expression for example

```
="D:\MyProject\ReportingViews\Report2.rdlc"
```

i Also Give only Name

```
Report2.rdlc
```

Comment: Can you show some more code of your implementation of the fill/load-behavior?

Comment: You have provided insufficient amount of code. Kindly provide more code so that we can easily get what you are into.

Answer (score 5):

This code will help you for open Report2 in Same Report Viewer on TextBoxName Click.

```
 // ---Load Report1 in report viewer on form load---
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Report1.rdlc"; //Here we set Set Report1 file path;
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

//---Load Report2 in same report viewer on TextBoxName Click 
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Report2.rdlc"; //Here we set Set Report2 file path
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Make sure File property of Report1 and Report2 as follows

> Build Action = Content

and

> Copy to output directory = Copy always

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the report property that you are talking about. If you want to open multiple reports from report viewer then you may do like this in your code page.

```
if(ddlDropdown.SelectedValue == 1)
{
 ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportsFolder\\report1.rdlc";
}
else if(ddlDropdown.SelectedValue == 2)
{
ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportsFolder\\report2.rdlc";
}
```